# How can Tanjiro become a Hashira in Demon slayer?

Tags: demon-slayer

How can a demon slayer become a hashira? What are the requirements? Is there any exam conducted to become hashira? No one has defeated 12th upper demon before, so I believe that is not the condition.

Comment: Slight correction, it is untrue to say none of the 12 demon moons have been felled before, quite a few of them have fallen over time, mostly assorted members of the Lower Ranks (ranks 7-12) but at least one of the Upper Ranks has also fallen. It was noted that it has been over 100 years since the last time an Upper Rank was killed but numerous members of the Lower Ranks have been killed by Hashira over time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not needed to kill a upper demon to become a Hashira if you can fulfill the other condition.

> To be a member of the Hashira, a Demon Slayer must be among the strongest combatants in the entirety of the Demon Slayer Corps. There are two known methods (both extremely difficult) that allow one to prove that they are worthy of becoming a Hashira: **the first method is to accumulate a demon kill count of at least 50 as a Kinoe-ranked Demon Slayer**, or slay a member of the Twelve Kizuki. The second method is being a Tsuguko of a Hashira, which requires immense talent.
>
> <sub>https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Hashira</sub>

Comment: tanjiro defeated upper moon will he become hashira?

Comment: @SayedMohdAli that would be Manga spoilers. Anyways, he didn't defeated UMDs alone as he had help from fellow Hashiras.